# Change element order in return of web method

Tags: c#, web-services

If in the WSDL definition of one of my web methods, I have something like this:

```
<s:complexType name="ExampleType">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element name="Element1" type="s:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
        <s:element name="Element2" type="s:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
        <s:element name="Element3" type="s:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Is it possible to change the order that these elements are returned to the client?

Method being called is something like this:

```
public static IList<ExampleType> WebMethod(string number)
{
    IList<ExampleType> listOfExampleType = GetExampleType();
    return listOfExampleType;
}
```

Comment: How is the WSDL being generated?

Comment: This is the one generated automatically.

Comment: Can I see the C# method that it's generated from?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Added to the question. Is that what you've asked?

Comment: Yes, thank you. What does `ExampleType` look like? If it's got three properties or fields named `Element1`, `Element2`, and `Element3`, I would just try reordering them in the C#. If it's not your class, you're probably stuck. I don't understand at all why you would need to reorder them anyway, though.

Comment: I was wondering if there's not a simple way to do that by customizing the WSDL, but reordering the elements in the class will do just fine. Thank you!